# AWS Sagemaker - df.to_csv error write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to save a file to S3 bucket from sagemaker instance. and below line throws an error!

```
df.to_csv("s3://informatri/Drug_Data_Cleaned.csv"), index = False)
```

```
error - 
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-d33896172c11> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 a.to_csv("s3://informatri/{}".format('Drug_Data_Cleaned.csv'), index = False)

/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_mxnet_p27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, tupleize_cols, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal)
   3018                                  doublequote=doublequote,
   3019                                  escapechar=escapechar, decimal=decimal)
-> 3020         formatter.save()
   3021 
   3022         if path_or_buf is None:

/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_mxnet_p27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.pyc in save(self)
    170                 self.writer = UnicodeWriter(f, **writer_kwargs)
    171 
--> 172             self._save()
    173 
    174         finally:

/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_mxnet_p27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.pyc in _save(self)
    272     def _save(self):
    273 
--> 274         self._save_header()
    275 
    276         nrows = len(self.data_index)

/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_mxnet_p27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.pyc in _save_header(self)
    240         if not has_mi_columns or has_aliases:
    241             encoded_labels += list(write_cols)
--> 242             writer.writerow(encoded_labels)
    243         else:
    244             # write out the mi

TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str
```

I tried the following:

```
df.to_csv("s3://informatri/Drug_Data_Cleaned.csv"), index = False, encoding = 'utf-8', sep = '\t')
```

I still get the same error. If I do only:

```
df.to_csv("Drug_Data_Cleaned.csv"), index = False)
```

It gets saved locally all fine. So not a problem with dataframe or the name etc. It has to do something with saving to S3 bucket.
I have used similar ways to save to s3 bucket many times in the past and it has worked perfectly fine. Hence, I was wondering why the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem.

The error was that the Sagemaker ipynb notebook was opened in conda_python2.7 or so. Just re-wrote the script in conda_python3 and then everything worked fine :)